# navigate inside createBrowserRouter only change URL but doesn't render the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I try to navigate users to personal page after they click sign in button. After clicking sign in button, the URL changed, and a toast warning was shown, but the screen stayed the same.

I've tried to navigate to other pages in handleSignIn function. For example, "member/:memberID", "member-info", and "/", but they all have the same bug. Even navigate to "/" failed, so I guess it wasn't caused by Protect Route. However, if I create another button `<button onClick={() => {navigate('/')}}>gogo</button>` in Sign in page and click it, the Home component can rendered successfully.

I've tried to add `navigate(0)` after the original navigate. This could render the correct component on page but it doesn't seem like a best approach. I have viewed multiple stackoverflow posts, however didn't find the explaintion and solution of this situation. Stuck here few days, appreciate any help!

1. main.tsx

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    <ToastContainer />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

2. RootLayout.tsx

```
const RootLayout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
      <ScrollRestoration />
    </div>
  )
}

export default RootLayout
```

3. App.tsx

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route path='/' element={<RootLayout />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='signin' element={<SignIn />} />
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
          <Route path='member/:memberID' element={<Member />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='member-info' element={<ProtectedMemberInfoRoute />} />
        <Route path='*' element={<NoMatch />} />
      </Route>
    )
  )

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />
}

export default App
```

4. Signin/index.tsx

```
const SignIn: React.FC = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  
  const handleSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, userEmail, userPassword)
      const userID = userCredential.user.uid
      const userDoc = await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', userID))

        if (userDoc.data()?.userFinishedInfo) {
          toast.success(`Welcome back, ${userDoc.data()?.username}`, {
            position: 'top-right',
            autoClose: 1000,
            hideProgressBar: false,
            closeOnClick: false,
            pauseOnHover: false,
            draggable: false,
            progress: undefined,
            theme: 'light'
          })
          navigate(`/member/${userID}`)
        } else {
          toast.warn(`You haven't finish your profile`, {
            position: 'top-right',
            autoClose: 1000,
            hideProgressBar: false,
            closeOnClick: false,
            pauseOnHover: false,
            draggable: false,
            progress: undefined,
            theme: 'light'
          })
          navigate('/member-info')
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
        toast.warn(`Incorrect email or password`, {
          position: 'top-right',
          autoClose: 1000,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: false,
          pauseOnHover: false,
          draggable: false,
          progress: undefined,
          theme: 'light'
        })
      })
  }

  return (
    <div className='h-screen-256px flex w-full flex-col items-center justify-center'>
      ...
      <button
        className='h-fit w-fit rounded-full bg-blue-500 p-4 text-white hover:bg-blue-600'
        onClick={() => handleSignIn()}
      >
        Sign In
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          navigate('/')
        }}
      >
        gogo
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SignIn
```

6. package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "18.2.0",
  "react-toastify": "9.1.3",
  "zustand": "4.4.7",
  "@firebase/firestore": "4.4.0",
  "uuid": "9.0.1",
  "tailwindcss": "3.3.6",
  "firebase": "10.7.1",
  "react-router-dom": "6.21.0"
},
```

---

Update on 2023.12.18

I somehow fixed this problem, and the result looks smooth. If someone like me also stuck at this point, hope this could give you some inspiration. Fighting!

- Creating a route protector to wrap SignIn component.
- Navigating via `<Navigate>` element, rather then use `useNavigate()` to redirect in handleSignIn function.

1. ProtectedSignInRoute.tsx

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import SignIn from '../../pages/Signin'
import { useUserStore } from '../../store/useUser'

const ProtectedSignInRoute = () => {
  const { isSignIn, userID, isLoadedUserDoc, userDoc } = useUserStore()

  if (isLoadedUserDoc && isSignIn && userDoc?.userFinishedInfo) {
    return <Navigate to={`/member/${userID}`} />
  } else if (isLoadedUserDoc && isSignIn && !userDoc?.userFinishedInfo) {
    return <Navigate to='/member-info' />
  } else {
    return <SignIn />
  }
}

export default ProtectedSignInRoute
```

2. App.tsx

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route path='/' element={<RootLayout />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='signin' element={<ProtectedSignInRoute />} /> // this line
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
          <Route path='member/:memberID' element={<Member />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='member-info' element={<ProtectedMemberInfoRoute />} />
        <Route path='*' element={<NoMatch />} />
      </Route>
    )
  )

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />
}

export default App
```

Comment: Use of React.StrictMode: React.StrictMode can sometimes cause unexpected behaviors during development due to its nature of double-invoking certain lifecycle methods. Try removing React.StrictMode temporarily to see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "...tried to navigate to all other pages in handleSignIn function, all failed..."? *Other than* `"member/:memberID"` and `"member-info"` what routes are accessible? Are you saying that specifically only `"member/:memberID"` and `"member-info"` aren't working? Or is it perhaps only the protected routes that have an issue? Can you [edit] to clarify what the specific issue is and include a more complete [mcve]? What does `ProtectedRoute` do? I suspect you've some Firebase logic there blocking the routes.

Comment: @AdesojiAlu I wouldn't say that the `StrictMode` component causes "unexpected behavior" in non-production builds so much as it helps expose bad/poor implementations and logic on your part. In other words, it's *your* code causing the unexpected behavior and `StrictMode` is surfacing it to you so you can fix it.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you so much for replying!  I've edited and updated minimal reproductive example link to the top of the post.

In the CodeSandbox example, the routes available are "member/:memberID", "member-info", and "/". Navigate one of these routes in handleSignIn function in SignIn component all got the same bug - url changed but component couldn't render. So I assume it wasn't caused by protected route.

Comment: Do you have a test account we could sign in with to test the `handleSignIn` functionality? Or is it possible to create a [mcve] that isn't coupled to Firebase? I could start mocking stuff but I'm afraid I'll end up mocking the code that is causing the problem and the routing/navigation will work as expected.

Comment: I think the issue is that the app doesn't set the `isSignIn` (*and other related state*) state when successfully signing in, and so when the imperative navigation to the member routes is effected, the zustand state is yet to reflect any authenticated user and so the user is bounced back off the route back to `"/signin"` to log in. *Maybe* calling `navigate` in a `setTimeout` is enough to place the navigation action at the end of the event queue and allow `onAuthStateChanged` to detect the auth change and enqueue the state updates so the protected routes are accessible.

Comment: Sure, test@gmail.com and password 123456. Or you may sign up multiple accounts (any fake email and password will work) and sign in to test the handleSignIn funcitonality. 

I tried your suggestion of using setTimeout, the url will change after 5 sec but still render nothing new. I checked console.log and it showed that after signing in, almost immediately zustand state of "isSignIn" has updated to true, and got the correct document data from Firestore.

Comment: @AdesojiAlu Thanks for replying! I tried removing it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry for delay. It seems the sandbox has some additional firebase issues/errors now, but it sounds like you were also able to resolve it yourself. Cheers.

Comment: No worries. Super grateful for your help and guidance! Really help me a lot. Hope you have a wonderful December! Thanks again!